# provision profile

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I have an application, it worked on the iPhone OS 3.0 with SDK 3.0.

with iPhone OS 3.0.1 I did the update and it seems o.k.:

ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0\ (7A341) /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1

But when I want to install my application on the device I get:
"Code Sign error: Provisioning profile '...' can't be found"

In XCode/Window/Organizer: "A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain"

Should I change the provision profile somehow? It was created for iPhone OS 3.0.
Should I change smth. in my keychain?

Thank you so much for your help!
Alexandra

Answer (score 1):

you can try to edit the project file in project.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj find all CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY and remove them, then re-open the project and re-set the mobile provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

Your signing identity/Provisioning file may have gotten deleted or expired.  Check your provisioning profile in the Organizer window of Xcode to see what its status is.

Answer (score 0):

1) I have deleted and added the profile in Organizer.

2) In the "build" of the current Project "Code Signing Identity" for Developer with the profile number "C44211F-..." can be choosed. So I choose it.

3) By starting the application as "Device-3.0-Release" -  error: Provisioning profile "C44211F-...." can't be found